# using same Progressbars in multiple Frames UWP

Tags: c#, progress-bar, speech-recognition, uwp

I have an application which works fine with VoiceControlled navigation. But now I am having a few problems with the UWP GUI.

What I want to do is the following:

> "add milk"

activates

```cs
private async void addMilk()
{
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher
                 .RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
                           () =>
        {
            this.milk.Value = milk.Value + 25;
        });                
}
```

This works more than fine in the `MainPage`. But when I go to `NextPage` with the same `progressbar` named `milk`, it does not add it to that one but the one on `MainPage` although I am on `NextPage`

Does anybody have a clear solution how to tackle this problem?

Comment: In which class is this method defined? `MainPage`?

Comment: The methods for the progressbars are in the MainPage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not passing the updated `milk` value to the next page. You can either pass it as a paramter or you can update your data store and make sure to read from the data store after navigation to `NextPage`.